# Spring Integration - reusing components

Tags: spring-integration

Is there any way to reuse @Transformer or any other components in Spring Integration?

I have transformer like below which i want to use multiple times in same flow. I feel we cannot do it as it is tied with channel. Is this correct?

```
@Transformer(inputChannel = "fileInputChannel" , outputChannel =  "mappingChannel")
public List<Map<String, String>> readFile(SLFile slfile){
    log.info("File Reader : " + slfile.getPath()+ slfile.getFileName());

    List<Map<String, String>> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    CSVFormat csvFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader();

    File file = new File(slfile.getPath()+ slfile.getFileName());

    try(CSVParser parser = new CSVParser(new FileReader(file), csvFormat)){
        parser.getRecords().stream().map(e ->  dataList.add(e.toMap())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        log.info(dataList);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("File read Error : " + e);
    }

    return dataList;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with that style of configuration.

With XML configuration, you can reference the same `@Transform` method from multiple places (because the channels are defined in the XML, not the annotation).

```
<int:transformer ... ref="myTBean" method="readFile" />
...
<int:transformer ... ref="myTBean" method="readFile" />
```

With the Java DSL style of configuration, you can reuse the transformer in multiple places...

```
...
.transform(readFile())
...
.transform(readFile())
...
```

With the annotation-style configuration alone, you would have to do something like

```
@Transformer(inputChannel = "fileInputChannel1" , outputChannel =      "mappingChannel1")
public List<Map<String, String>> readFile1(SLFile slfile){
    return readFile(slfile);
}

...

@Transformer(inputChannel = "fileInputChannelN" , outputChannel =      "mappingChannelN")
public List<Map<String, String>> readFileN(SLFile slfile){
    return readFile(slfile);
}
```

We don't currently allow multiple `@Transformer` annotations on a single method.

Comment: Got it. Thank you